# Named Arguments jQuery Function

Tags: jquery, function, arguments

I would like to pass arguments to a function in a list, without having to keep a certain order and be able to pass only one, or no argument at all and so on.

I think the code is mostly ok, but for some reason I get the message that my arguments are not defined, although the function passes the object with the arguments.

What am I missing?

```js
function positioning(options) {

  var defaults = {
    position: "static",
    background: "lightblue",
    height: "100px"
  };

  var params = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

  var div1 = $('#div1'),
    div2 = $('#div2');

  console.log(options);
  console.log(params);
  console.log("position: " + position);

  div2.css('position', position);
  div2.css('background', background);
  div2.css('height', height);
}

$('button').click(function() {

  positioning({
    height: "200px"
  });
});
```

```css
#div1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: lightgrey;
}
#div2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: lightblue;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<button type="button">trigger function</button>
```

Comment: `console.log("position: " + params.position);`, in your function scope there is no variable named `position` instead it is a property of the `params` obejct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those aren't variables but properties of the `params` object.

Change

```
div2.css('position', position);
div2.css('background', background);
div2.css('height', height);
```

to

```
div2.css('position', params.position);
div2.css('background', params.background);
div2.css('height', params.height);
```

Comment: fantastic, thanks so much for the quick reply, works like a charm! and thanks everyone else!

Answer (score 1):

In your function scope there is no variable named position instead it is a property of the params object.

Since the params are css properties, you can use the css variant that takes an object as its value instead of setting each one

```js
function positioning(options) {

  var defaults = {
    position: "static",
    background: "lightblue",
    height: "100px"
  };

  var params = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

  var div1 = $('#div1'),
    div2 = $('#div2');

  console.log(options);
  console.log(params);
  console.log("position: " + params.position);

  div2.css(params);

  //div2.css('position', params.position);
  //div2.css('background', params.background);
  //div2.css('height', params.height);
}

$('button').click(function() {

  positioning({
    height: "200px"
  });
});
```

```css
#div1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: lightgrey;
}
#div2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: lightblue;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<button type="button">trigger function</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use `div2.css(params);` since the `css()` function will take an object as an input.

If you want to refer to `position` or `background` separately, then you need to use the `.` operator with param like `param.position`, `param.background` etc or use `param['position']` or `param['background']`.

```js
function positioning(options) {

  var defaults = {
    position: "static",
    background: "lightblue",
    height: "100px"
  };

  var params = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

  var div1 = $('#div1'),
    div2 = $('#div2');

  console.log(options);
  console.log(params);
  div2.css(params);
}

$('button').click(function() {

  positioning({
    height: "200px"
  });
});
```

```css
#div1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: lightgrey;
}
#div2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: lightblue;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<button type="button">trigger function</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Defaults param is an object. Read like :

```
  console.log("position: " + defaults.position);
  div2.css('position', defaults.position);
  div2.css('background', defaults.background);
  div2.css('height', defaults.height);
```

```js
function positioning(options) {

  var defaults = {
    position: "static",
    background: "lightblue",
    height: "100px"
  };

  var params = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

  var div1 = $('#div1'),
    div2 = $('#div2');

  console.log(options);
  console.log(params);
  console.log("position: " + defaults.position);

  div2.css('position', defaults.position);
  div2.css('background', defaults.background);
  div2.css('height', defaults.height);
}

$('button').click(function() {

  positioning({
    height: "200px"
  });
});
```

```css
#div1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: lightgrey;
}
#div2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: lightblue;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<button type="button">trigger function</button>
```